# What are the characters called in a book

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, books

In English, we have words for the characters in something/the people acting something. An example would be "The cast of the film was very talented."

Would it be right to say "The cast of the book was...", or would this be incorrect as the characters in a novel are fictional?

Comment: Cast (of characters) refers to actors in a movie or show. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cast

Comment: "Cast of characters" is often used metaphorically to refer to a group of (probably strange) people, whether in real life or fiction.  Whether it works for your case is hard to say.

Answer (score 4):

The term "cast", meaning actors, is reserved for the theatre and is not used for characters in a book. In a quick search I was unable to find a collective noun for book characters, so the best option is probably to say "The characters in the book were … (richly drawn / absurd / poorly developed / etc)".